# how to make azure policy script that limits the number of vm created per resource group?

Tags: azure, policy

I want to make azure policy script that limits the number of vm created per resource group to a maximum of 2?

What is wrong with the policy in below code block?

```
{
  "mode": "All",
  "policyRule": {
    "if": {
      "allOf": [
        {
          "field": "type",
          "equals": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines"
        }
      ]
    },
    "then": {
      "effect": "deny",
      "details": {
        "type": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines",
        "existenceCondition": {
          "field": "count",
          "equals": "[parameters('maxVmCount')]"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "parameters": {
    "maxVmCount": {
      "type": "Integer",
      "metadata": {
        "displayName": "Allowed Virtual Machine capacities"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I want to create a policy that allows up to two virtual machines to be created for each newly created resource group.

Comment: Azure Policy doesn't directly support counting resources within a resource group before creating an VM.